# Xcode add reference to files instead of copy

Tags: xcode

I have created my framework that i want to add in my project. What i do is:

- In my project i chose Xcode -> File -> Add Files to..
- In prompt window i go for framework directory, chose .xcodeproj file
- Check "Copy items if needed" and "Added folders - Create groups" radio button

What i expect - .xcodeproj that contain my framework is **added and copied** to my project

What i got - i can see file in Xcode, but not in folder when my app exist. So, when i try to Delete -> Move to trash my framework, it delete it in folder when it was created (not my project folder).

I can't figure out how to **actually add and copy** file instead of reference to it.